# Requests to VM Ware Fusion guest fail when Cisco Anyconnect VPN is active

Tags: networking, vpn, vmware-fusion

I'm on Mac OS 11.6.5 Big Sur running a Windows 2019 Server guest from VM Ware fusion 12.2.3. The VPN is Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 4.10.00093.

My local network is on `10.0.0.0/24`

The VM is network is set to "Share with my mac" NAT and is on DHCP. The address assigned is `172.16.249.128`

With the VPN *not* connected, I can access services from the host to the guest. e.g. access a web server on the windows vm.

However as soon as I connect the VPN, I loose access to the VM. From inside the VM I can access the WAN but nothing from the VPN. What's worse is after disconnecting the the VPN, I still can't access the VM. Restarting Fusion's services doesn't work and I end up having to reboot the mac.

The Cisco config is supplied by our company IT. They have advised it's setup for split tunneling: `10.0.0.0/8`, `194.xx.xx.0/21`, some ranges in `192.168.0.0` -> tunnel, Anything else -> to default route (normally internet)

I've ready a bunch of fusion community posts that have similar issues, but they have all been patched as of fusion 12.2.3, afaik. Of course all this was working before Apple changed to NetworkExtension framework.

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If your local network is `10.0.0.0/24`, it would seem the Cisco VPN is capturing this, and routing all outgoing traffic over the tunnel (`10.0.0.0/8` includes `10.0.0.0/24`)   When the VPN tunnel is up, all traffic from your Mac bound for your local network ought to go over the VPN tunnel.   You can check this by activating the VPN and attempting to access something else on your network (printer maybe?)  I expect the connection will fail.

Since the `172.16.249.128` that Fusion is using for your VM falls inside the `172.16.0.0/12` network space identified by [RFC-1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918) one would expect that it is not going to be affected by your VPN tunnel.  However Fusion has to set up a routing rule on your machine that says that traffic bound for `172.16.249.128` needs to be NATted to your local IP in the `10.0.0.0/24`.  Since this range is captured by the VPN tunnel, the traffic is instead routed over the tunnel.

As for why this behavior persists even after the tunnel is torn down, and the AnyConnect client has been quit...  Well, that is a long story.  Cisco does a terrible job of cleaning up routes when the AnyConnect client is quit.

**Possible solution:** move your local subnet to something outside the ranges captured by that split tunnel.  You could for example make your home network `172.16.0.0/24`, and your NATted VPN network `172.16.1.0/24`.  I expect then that everything will work swimmingly, and you will also have access to your (printer? or other devices) to boot!

**To confirm the above is correct, do the following:**

1. Restart the computer, post the result of `netstat -rn`
2. Launch your Fusion VM, post the result of `netstat -rn`
3. Start AnyConnect and bring the tunnel up.  Post the result of `netstat -rn`
4. Quit Any Connect and post the result of `netstat -rn`